# Selenium python Rating stars click

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On a webpage I have a rating stars feedback that looks as follow:

[image]

When I hoover on the stars they became yellow and the source code changes.

this is the code when non of the stars are selected

[image]

I have 5 similar divs, same Class and configuration.

If I hoover and click on the 5th stars, they all became yellow and the source code changes to this for all the divs.

[image]

What I would like to do is target the fifth star and click it to set a rating. I tried with the `xpath` and `css_selector` but I keep getting errors.

with the xpath I tried this:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg' and contains(@class, 'sc-bFSanr BElwX')]"))).click()
```

But the code timed out.

and if I try with the css selector I get the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Can anyone please help me to understand how can I target any of the stars and click it?

Thank you very much for your help guys

Comment: Can you share the Page url ? looks like it's public. Those are svg elements, they are special kinda tag

Comment: can I send you the link in your email?

Comment: The CSS you tried is svg.sc-bFSanr.BElwX? (and I mean dots, not spaces) If you're before hover (after would be  bovwPI)

Comment: @Prophet nothing personal, its a link that works only for 1 person at the time.

Comment: OK, I understand

Comment: can I send you the link in your email?  - feel free to

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I solved the issue I had with the rating. I used the css_selector as before, and suddenly start working without any problem. Thank you so much guys